# Centering \vdots in Linear Mapping Equations

Tags: equations

I am trying to center the vertical dots, but I cant seem to do it - whatever I have tried, the dots remain left aligned. Below is the code that I have at the moment. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
\begin{align*}
    &T_0: V_0 \mapsto V_1 \\
    &T_1: V_1 \mapsto V_2 \\
    &T_2: V_2 \mapsto V_3 \\
    &\vdotswithin{\mapsto}\\
    &T_n: V_n \mapsto V_{n+1}
    \end{align*}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: My welcome to the TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it something like this you're after?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[2][M] {\eqmakebox[#1]{$\displaystyle#2$}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{alignat*}{2}
 & T_0 & : V_0 & \mapsto V_1 \\
  & T_1 & : V_1 & \mapsto V_2 \\
  & \eqmathbox{T_2} & : V_2 & \mapsto V_3 \\[-1.25ex]
 & \eqmathbox{\vdots} & &\vdotswithin{\mapsto}\\[-0.5ex]
  & T_n & : V_n & \mapsto V_{n+1}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX-SE! I think you should set the alignment point differently. (`\vdotswithin{\mapsto}` does not magically search for `\mapsto`s in the other lines and aligns the dots, it just centers them w.r.t. to a box of the corresponding size.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    T_0: V_0 &\mapsto V_1 \\
    T_1: V_1 &\mapsto V_2 \\
    T_2: V_2 &\mapsto V_3 \\
    &\vdotswithin{\mapsto}\\
    T_n: V_n &\mapsto V_{n+1}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]